# Determining periodic pattern when there is pattern which period is multiple of former

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, periodic, pattern

I have periodic signal, say, it has year period, yearly pattern. I want to check if also has quarterly pattern.
Event if there is no visible quarterly pattern, Fourier Transform of this signal has peaks on all frequencies which are multiples of 1/year frequency. They're gradually decreasing. I understand why they're present but don't now how I can remove this effect.
How do I tell if signal has quarterly pattern?

Comment: I found https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15378/fourier-transform-with-periodicity-at-the-harmonic-frequency?rq=1 just after I posted this question.